# Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string? what is happening to cause this error?

Tags: php, sql, cookies, mysqli

I am trying to rename a file and then upload it. I want to save the filename as the cookie called user. the cookie called user has a value e.g. 168188. lets say the original file was called profilepic.png. when it is uploaded it will be called 168188.png.

I now get this error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string. how do I solve this and what is happening to cause this error?

```
        <?php
            include('connect.php');

            $sqlcookie = $_COOKIE['user'];
            $resultcookie = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlcookie);
            $countcookie = mysqli_connect($resultcookie);

        $target_dir = "C:\Users\Mashood\Documents\UoCRateMe!\uploads\uploads";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $newname = $countcookie;
        // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check !== false) {
                echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                $uploadOk = 1;
                ?>

                <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

                <script>
                function goBack() {
                    window.history.back();
                }
                </script>
                <?php
            } else {
                echo "File is not an image.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
                        ?>

                <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

                <script>
                function goBack() {
                    window.history.back();
                }
                </script>
                <?php
            }
        }
        // Check if file already exists
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
                    ?>

                <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

                <script>
                function goBack() {
                    window.history.back();
                }
                </script>
                <?php
        }
        // Check file size
        if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
                    ?>

                <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

                <script>
                function goBack() {
                    window.history.back();
                }
                </script>
                <?php
        }
        // Allow certain file formats
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
        && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
                    ?>

                <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

                <script>
                function goBack() {
                    window.history.back();
                }
                </script>
                <?php
        }
        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
                    ?>

                <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

                <script>
                function goBack() {
                    window.history.back();
                }
                </script>
                <?php
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                //bool rename ( string $oldname , string $newname [, resource $context ] )
                //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

                ` rename ( $target_file , $newname);`
                ?>
                <?php
                echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

                include('picdbstore.php');
                        ?>

                <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

                <script>
                function goBack() {
                    window.history.back();
                }
                </script>
                <?php
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                        ?>

                <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

                <script>
                function goBack() {
                    window.history.back();
                }
                </script>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: I think you used the wrong function here, `mysqli_connect`. Maybe you meant to use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php? Also does `$_COOKIE['user']` contain a SQL query? If so that is very insecure, if not it is unclear what you are doing there..

Comment: @chris85 the cookie contains text from an input box. let's say the input box contained the word 'test'. that would mean the cookie value was 'test'. i would then want the uplaoded file to be called 'test'. do you understand what i want to achieve now?

Comment: Look at `$resultcookie = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlcookie);`. Your query is `test`, that is not a valid SQL query.

Comment: @chris85 how do I make it into a correct query?

Comment: What are you trying to query?

Comment: query is after connect !! are you echoing something in the db file ? check line number of error

Comment: @zod this is the code in connect.php

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>connection</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbrateme');  
if (!$connection){ 
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
   header('Location: dcf.php');
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'dbrateme'); 
if (!$select_db){ 
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error());  
}
?>
</body>
</html>